# What is the rule behind this Triangle's Vector Addition?

Tags: vectors

I have just watched this lecture Lec 5 | MIT 18.02 Multivariable Calculus, Fall 2007 https://youtu.be/57jzPlxf4fk?t=34m5s

Here's the diagram

[Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSbQr.png)

Since the triangle law is $\vec A + \vec B = \vec C$, then why $\vec{OP} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AB} + \vec{BP}$?

Shouldn't it be $\vec{OP} + \vec{BP} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AB}$ , thus $\vec{OP} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AB} - \vec{BP}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No, since $\vec{BP}$ is directed towards $P$, thus it must say $\vec{OP} - \vec{BP} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AB}$ which is exactly what is stated in the video.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you have typo. Shouldn't the $\vec{AP}$ be $\vec{AB}$?

Comment: @Yulianto yep. sorry